# How can I write multi line equations with alignment in inline math mode?

Tags: math-mode, environments, amsmath, align

Is there any way to override the fact that certain environments in LaTeX are automatically "displayed"?  One such example is the `align*` environment.  I want to keep my aligned equations inline.  So basically I want something like

```
\begin{align*}
x+y&=z\\
u+v&=w
\end{align*}
```

embedded into a line of text.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In such cases you could simply use the `aligned` environment within inline math instead of `align*`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
text
$\begin{aligned}
x+y&=z\\
u+v&=w
\end{aligned}$
more text
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @Stefan, thanks...I wasn't aware that there was an aligning environment outside of math mode.  Doh!

Comment: @Kristen: It's not outside math mode, but inside inline math mode.

Comment: I wonder if it is essentially the same as `\halign{#\hfill&&~#\hfill\cr text&$\eqalign{x+y&=z\cr u+v&=w}$&more text\cr}\bye` in plain.

Comment: how do I do it without the vertical centering

Comment: @theonlygusti found a solution?

Comment: @theonlygusti @Colo for anyone coming here in the future, here is the solution: use the `t` option to the aligned environment, as in `\begin{aligned}[t]` (taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153305/292581)