# Left-aligned, inline-ish equations

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

I'm attempting to create a template for writing up Physics problems sets. A lot of these problem sets can involve short, simple calculations. For example:

[image: simple calculation]

I attempt to typeset this calculation with something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{align*}
\omega_{0}&=\sqrt{k_{0}/M}\\
&=\sqrt{5/10}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{align*}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

But the result ends up looking something like this:

[image: damn]

Which looks terrible to me - it's such a short calculation, it looks absurd slapped in the center of the document like that, especially without any text before or after.

Alternatively, I can just use the inline equation form,

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
$\omega_{0}=\sqrt{k_{0}/M}$\\
$=\sqrt{5/10}$\\
$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

But that yields something like this, which loses the nice formatting of an equation array.

[image: damn again]

Essentially, what I'm aiming for is a way to typeset the equation as though it were just inline text (i.e. with the $\omega_{0}$ coming directly after the 1., as in the inline form), but preserving the alignment and formatting of an equation array. The closest I've gotten was with the `fleqn` option and a negative `\vspace` to put it on the same line, but even that didn't look right, as `fleqn` just makes the equation *more* leftward, but doesn't actually align it with the margin of the text.

Comment: Don't do it like this: if it's an inline equation, then let it be an inline equation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In-line math mode is the way to go. But you will need the `aligned` environment from »[amsmath](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)«. You can align it to the top with respect to the current line.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}  % loads »amsmath«

\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item
      \(
        \begin{aligned}[t]
          \omega_{0} &= \sqrt{k_{0}/M}\\
                     &= \sqrt{5/10}\\
                     &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
        \end{aligned}
      \)
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: The square root symbol looks "broken". Do you know if this is an issue with the font?

Comment: That's perfect! I had tried `aligned`, but I wasn't aware of the `[t]` option, so it didn't line up with the text the way I wanted it to. And Svend, I see that too, but I didn't do that when I typeset the equation, so I think that's just an issue with whatever pdf viewer the image was rendered in - I've seen similar problems with TeXShop's built in pdf view.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: An issue with the viewer at the chosen magnification. In other levels of magnification it renders fine. The printed output should not be affected.

Answer (score 1):

For these kind of short derivations, a stack can frequently accomplish what you need.  In this case, I set the stackgap to 4pt for demonstration purposes (the default is 3pt) and invoke the stack with left alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\stackMath
\setstackgap{S}{4pt}
\begin{document}
1. $
\omega_o \mathrel{\Shortunderstack[l]{= \sqrt{k_0/M}\\= \sqrt{5/10}\\
  = \displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]